# output is not as expected it should print 12 not 102

Tags: c++, string

output should be 12 not 102 why is it not deleting all the zeros

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s="10002";
    for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
    if(s[i]=='0')
    s.erase(s.begin()+i);
    cout<<s;
}
```

Comment: You can use a debugger and step each iteration to see what happens. BTW, in C++20, you can simply write `std::erase(s, '0');`. Until C++20, you can do the same by combining `auto it = std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), '0');` and `s.erase(it, s.end());`.

Comment: also your indentation is terrible and will easily cause confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s skipping a value because the loop counter gets incremented even when you erase characters. You need to decrement `i` when you erase a 0

```
if (s[i] == 0) {
    s.erase(s.begin() + i);
    i--;
}
```

Comment: It works, but I don’t really like the underflow in case the string starts with a zero.

Comment: There won’t be underflow because the loop counter will be reset to zero if the first character is a zero.

Comment: I mean, you decrease idx to -1, and then increase it again to 0. It will of course work, but IMHO it's not really elegant, rather some sort of workaround.

Comment: I get what you’re saying. It’s a safe little piece of code but it does “feel” dirty

Answer (score 2):

Let's dry run your code.

1. `i = 0, s[0] != '0'` (does nothing)
2. `i = 1, s[1] = '0'` (it erases the `'0'` at second index, now the string is "1002")
3. `i = 2, s[2] = '0'` (it erases the `'0'` at third index, now the string is `"102"`)
4. `i = 3`, but the size of string is also `3`, so the loop breaks because of the condition `i<s.size()`.

Hence `102` is printed.

Answer (score 1):

As @DanMulin mentioned, it's skipping value because when you deleted a character, the `std::string` size is decreased but `i` keeps getting increased. To solve it, add a `i--`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s="10002";
    for(int i=0; i<s.size(); i++)
    {
        if(s[i]=='0')
        {
            s.erase(s.begin()+i); i--;
        }
    }
    std::cout << s;
}
```

Or to avoid this all together, you can use a `while` loop instead (which I recommended more when manipulating `std::strings`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s="10002";
    int inc = 0;
    while(inc < s.length())
    {
        while(s[inc] == '0') { s.erase(s.begin()+inc); }
        inc++;
    }
    std::cout << s;
}
```

Also, see

- [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
- [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.)